# Android barcode sdk

Tags: android, barcode

I need a barcode sdk/api that works directly on my app. I've found zxing which is free and works from the app too, but the developer do not recommends it.

Do you know any free alternative that works fine without having to download extra components and apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Scandid, they have a community licience which is free.